# Is there a way change a single line in a macro using a compile-time constant?

Tags: rust

So the thing is, I'm using macros to implement Add trait on my `mStruct`.
I tried to implement this trait on both `mStruct` and `&mStruct`, and they both returns `mStruct`. However, within each macro, I have a line that need to be different, otherwise it won't compile.

```
struct mStruct {
    // Variables
}

macro_rules! implement_add {
    ($type:ty, $output:ty, $is_ref_mode:literal) => {
        impl Add for $type {
            type Output = $output;
            fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
                if $is_ref_mode {
                    // Thing that don't compile if $is_ref_mode is false
                } else {
                    // Thing that don't compile if $is_ref_mode is true
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

implement_add!(mStruct, mStruct, false);
implement_add!(&mStruct, mStruct, true);
```

Can I do this with a macro, or should I write the same function twice and change this line by hand?

Comment: Consider making two match arms: one when true was given to `$is_ref_mode`, and the other when it is false. I saw [this page](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/mbe-macro-rules.html#matching) on possible matches and it lists that you could potentially match any tokens, so maybe it could work? Note: I'm not a rustacean, so what I just said could be nonsensical gibberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your macro that it has two arms. Something like this:

```rust
struct mStruct {
    // Variables
}

macro_rules! implement_add {
    ($type:ty, noref) => {
        impl Add for $type {
            type Output = $type;
            fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
                // self should be Self
            }
        }
    };
    ($type:ty, doref) => {
        // note here & before $type
        impl Add for &$type {
            type Output = $type;
            fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
                // self should be &Self
            }
        }
    };
}

implement_add!(mStruct, noref);
implement_add!(mStruct, doref);
```

Comment: Ah, so what I said wasn't exactly nonsense! Good to know. I suppose you could also use `true` and `false` but `noref` and deref` are more descriptive :)

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! But just to be clear, if I want to implement it only for `mStruct`, there's no point in using a macro, I can just implement it the normal way? Or does this solution offers an advantage I'm unaware of? Or is it maybe more idiomatic?

Comment: @er1t It depends on what you are trying to do. The point of macro is to reduce code repetition. So I understood, that you want to do this multiple times on multiple structs. If it is only one time thing, then definitely do this manually.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze Thank you so much for your quick answers! I guess I don't need macros after all!